# scanf counts accented letters as 2 characters in C, how to solve this?

Tags: c, scanf, non-ascii-characters

I have a problem and I can't find a solution anywhere, so here I am...

**My code** (only the interesting part):

```
char string[21];
scanf("%20s",string);
printf("%s", string);
```

**User:** 12345678901234567890  --->  12345678901234567890 (Works fine in that case)

**User:** éééééééééééééééééééé  --->  éééééééééé (The second part is gone because 'é' counts double)

I want the user to enter a name with a max length of 20, so I use `scanf("%20s",string)` and everything works just fine until you write an accented character... How can I fix that ?

**NOTES:** *(edited)* If possible, I want to keep using scanf() and not an other function (but an other function from a standard library *(and not an ASCII function lol)* is okay).

And most importantly I can't just write `scanf("%40s",string)` (I'm using `if(scanf("%d %20s %d:%d %c",string)==5)` as a condition).

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by other ASCII functions? What are ASCII functions?

Comment: *"The current standard, though, is Unicode which uses two bytes to represent all characters in all writing systems in the world in a single set.*" Unicode characters do not fit into  the```char``` type. You will have to use the functions declared in ```<wchar.h>``` header file. Or perhaps they may fit, depending on your OS, but you don't provide that information.

Comment: Yes sorry I don't know why I said ASCII, I was thinking of "standard libraries in C"

Comment: And thanks I'm going to try using ```<wchar.h>``` functions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utf8 characters have variable size. You can't use `%20s` to ensure 20 characters. Only to ensure 20 bytes (which is what you want the most: avoid memory overflow, and control how many bytes you write).

Note that you mention "ascii", but your strings are not made of ascii chars. Those are UTF-8. There is no such thing as `é` in ASCII.

Understand that, roughly, C doesn't really care of ASCII or UTF. It stores bytes it gets from stdin (so, probably from a terminal emulator. Or another program. Point is, it is not C job. Those are bytes coming from somewhere else, without meaning, outside not being 0) in a `char *`; and when you `printf` it just output those bytes to `stdout` (probably a terminal emulator also ; or another program that will read those bytes and decide what to do with it; or, historically, a serial printer; ...)

ASCII devices (and emulator, again, terminal emulator), decide to draw a cicle when they are pushed a 48 (`0`), a vertical bar 49, (`1`), ...

UTF-8 devices (or emulator) use a more complex protocl. And some bytes mean that they should wait for the next byte, to know what to draw.

I am pretty sure you already know that, but I wanted to describe it in a "down to earth" way, to clarify how C doesn't care. C send 2 bytes (for example). If the terminal emulator (or the physical terminal, or the printer, or the program listening the other side of a pipe, or...) decides to draw one or two symbols from it (depending on whether that receiving end consider those 2 bytes to be ascii or utf, or something else) is up to it. The emitting program (your C code) doesn't care.

Now, all that being said, there are helper functions in C that can be aware of utf8 encoding, and can cound the number of symbols that would be printed by the output device, if it is an utf8 one. Look at `mb_strlen` for example (and similar function of the same family).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Indeed I knew for UTF and ASCII but I didn't know how %20s works, so thanks, I am going to try it and I hope I'm going to find a solution to my problem.